# ArcGIS 10.5 auto-populating field in attribute table

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-10.5

I am having trouble auto-populating a field in the attribute table.

I would like to populate the `grid_code` column with sequential letters and numbers - i.e. `AAA001`, `AAA002` etc. I looked at previous threads on auto-populating, but was unable to get it to work.

Image of attribute table attached:

[image]

Comment: What previous Q&As have you looked at?

Comment: What feature storage is it? When do you want it to auto update? On create, on modify, now, later...?